# Avoiding cross-join when joining more than two tables in hive

Tags: hadoop, join, hive, cross-join, bigdata

```
select a.1,a.2,b.1,b.2,c.1
from a 
left join b on a.1=b.1
left join c on a.1=c.1;
```

I have to join more than two tables on a single column that they have in common , when i try to execute the above query the results are all wrong as the table b and c are cross joining and giving me multiple rows and since the table also involves some aggregations all the results are ending up same .how do i avoid the cross joining of the tables .

Comment: You are probably missing additional `join` keys.  Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: select a.1 - there should be syntax error, column name should not be digit